# Passing data back to controllers when struct model modified

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, struct

I have a series of `View Controllers` which pass a `struct` model object down the chain.

If a user modifies the value of a property on the model, I update the view controller's model instance, and now I need to inform the parent view controllers that this object's value has changed.

Previously I would have used `classes` over `structs` for my model object and so I wouldn't have this issue as the object would have been directly written to.

But since structs are pass by value, I have to update the state on other view controllers. I have been using a singleton Manager object to handle state changes through a call to updateModel(). Is there a better way?

Comment: I would use a delegate for this.

Comment: If you don't need a `copy` of the object, don't use a value type

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Following the Apple guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes) it seems structs are best suited for my model usage.

Comment: I suggest you learn about the Observer pattern, which is often the correct way for Views to learn about Model changes:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 1):

I have used something similar to this; keep a reference to the neighbouring view controller (with care to avoid a reference cycle) and a property observer on the `struct` property to update it when it changes.

This could also be updated prior to presenting a new view controller or before a segue, depending on your needs.

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {

    // Your struct
    var model: MyStruct? {
        didSet {
            if let pvc = previousVC {
                pvc.model = model
            }
        }
    }

    // Keep a reference to the previous view controller on your stack
    var previousVC: UIViewController?

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.model = MyStruct()
    }
}
```